# Is 4-in-a-row PSPACE-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity, gt.game-theory, board-games, combinatorial-game-theory

[This paper](https://www.cs.ru.nl/bachelors-theses/2017/Laurens_Kuiper___4467299___Axis-Parallel_Five-in-a-Row_is_PSPACE-Complete.pdf) by Laurens Kuiper shows that axis-parallel k-in-a-row is [PSPACE-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE-complete) in [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_complexity#Computational_complexity) for k ≥ 5, but leaves the question open for k = 4. Has there been any research progress on this question?